# How to sort columns based on row values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

```
pd.DataFrame({'Store':['A'],'Cycle':[1700],'ECycle':2300,'Bike':[1900],'Scooter':[1900]})
```

I have a dataframe as shown above. I would like to know if there's a simple way/built-in function to sort the columns of the dataframe as per the row values. So the output should be one of the following below.

```
pd.DataFrame({'Store':['A'],'Cycle':[1700],'Bike':[1900],'Scooter':[1900],'ECycle':[2300]})

pd.DataFrame({'Store':['A'],'Cycle':[1700],'Scooter':[1900],'Bike':[1900],'ECycle':[2300]})
```

Is there a way to achieve this without defining lengthy custom functions?

Comment: Do you always have one non-numeric column? What should happen if you have several rows?

Answer (score 2):

First convert first column to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then sorting by row by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `axis=1`:

```
print(df.set_index('Store').sort_values('A', axis=1))
       Cycle  Bike  Scooter  ECycle
Store                              
A       1700  1900     1900    2300
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Store':['A', 'B'],'Cycle':[1700, 10],
                   'ECycle':[2300, 0],'Bike':[1900, 2],'Scooter':[1900, 1]})
    
out = df.set_index('Store').sort_values('A', axis=1)
print (out)
       Cycle  Bike  Scooter  ECycle
Store                              
A       1700  1900     1900    2300
B         10     2        1       0

out = df.set_index('Store').sort_values('B', axis=1)
print (out)
       ECycle  Scooter  Bike  Cycle
Store                              
A        2300     1900  1900   1700
B           0        1     2     10
```

If need sorting all columns without first (then columns names not match for all rows):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Store')

df1[:] = np.sort(df1)
print (df1)
       Cycle  ECycle  Bike  Scooter
Store                              
A       1700    1900  1900     2300
B          0       1     2       10
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.iloc[:, 1:]), index=df['Store'])
print (df1)
          0     1     2     3
Store                        
A      1700  1900  1900  2300
B         0     1     2    10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Store': ['A'], 'Cycle': [1700], 'ECycle': [2300], 'Bike': [1900], 'Scooter': [1900]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

row_to_sort = 0

sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=df.index[row_to_sort], axis=1)

print(sorted_df)
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, you can't compare strings and integers

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mix of numeric and non numeric data and want to sort the numeric ones, leaving the non-numeric first you can use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` and take advantage of the `na_position` parameter of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = df[pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[0], errors='coerce')
           .sort_values(na_position='first').index]
```

Alternatively, using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

out = df.iloc[:, np.argsort(pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[0], errors='coerce')
                              .fillna(-np.inf))]
```

Output:

```
  Store  Cycle  Bike  Scooter  ECycle
0     A   1700  1900     1900    2300
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the numeric portion and then `concat` it, so that avoiding the option of making first column as `index`.

```
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0], pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0,1:].sort_values()).T], axis = 1)
print(df)

Store Cycle  Bike Scooter ECycle
0     A  1700  1900    1900   2300
```